# LINQ join: Collection that has no data or null

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collection of data, and these are two related to each other. for example: ID, PersonName and other collection is PhoneUnit, PersonID...

I have to do linq here something line

```
var results = from people in person join phone in phones.DefaultIfEmpty() on people.ID equals phone.PersonID   select new { people.PersonName, phone.PhoneUnit == null ? "empty" : phone.PhoneUnit };
```

but my problem is, sometimes the Phone collection returns 0 results because there is no data in the database. But I still need to show the PersonName and PhoneUnit

I got a NullReferenceException. Please let me know what I'm missing here. Thanks

Comment: You need to replace the INNER JOIN with a LEFT OUTER JOIN as outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: I will try this one and I will let you know. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do a left join try this:

```
var results = from people in person 
              join phone in phones on people.ID equals phone.PersonID into phone_j  
              from phone in phone_j.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { 
                           people.PersonName
                           phone.PhoneUnit 
                         };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
people.ID equals phone.PersonID
```

here is your problem, if your phone is null, this statement will never get you any result other than null.

Comment: Hi, That is what I thought. But I guess need to do a left join here. I did a research and need to add a DefaultIfEmpty. And I did. But still no results/null exception